# How to install and run Irwin cheat detector on my PC?

Tags: ubuntu, python, application, python3

I followed every thing on [the document](https://github.com/clarkerubber/irwin), but I am still getting errors when running it from terminal with this command

```
python3 app.py --no-assess --no-report
```

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'conf/server_config.json' #11
```

Can anyone explain how to install it in the right way?

I am using ubuntu 18.04. I installed tensorflow, and all the other python libs successfully. However, I don't know how to get into the gui without any  errors that crash my terminal.
UPDATE:
AFTER I CREATED MY CONFIG FILE THAT'S MY CONFIG FILE CODE  "

```
{
  "api": {
    "url": "https://lichess.org/",
    "token": "token"
  },
  "stockfish": {
    "threads": 4,
    "memory": 2048,
    "nodes": 4500000,
    "update": false
  },
  "db": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "authenticate": false,
    "authentication": {
      "username": "root",
      "password": ""
    }
    //27017
  },
  "irwin": {
    "train": {
      "batchSize": 5000,
      "cycles": 80
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I looked at the code. The file does not exist. **Maybe** this is the file that you were to make, but they gave the wrong name. Also consider the fixing the url.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor i get this error after changing the config file name Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 16, in <module>
    config = ConfigWrapper.new('conf/server_config.json')
  File "/home/shar/Desktop/the irwin/irwin-master/conf/ConfigWrapper.py", line 15, in new

Comment: It looks like there is part of that error message missing. However I am not going to debug a 3rd party program. You should ask the devs, and file a bug report.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug [in a Github repository](https://github.com/clarkerubber/irwin) and a [bug was already filed](https://github.com/clarkerubber/irwin/issues/11) with the developers.  cc@ctrl-alt-delor  **:-)**

Comment: @shar: It works for me. I created `conf/server_config.json` and ran `python3 app.py --no-assess --no-report` in *the same* directory. Post output of `ls -l conf/server_config.json` done in the directory where you ran `app.py`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk i getting this error after doing that Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 16, in <module>
    config = ConfigWrapper.new('conf/server_config.json')
  File "/home/shar/Desktop/the irwin/irwin-master/conf/ConfigWrapper.py", line 15, in new

Comment: I'm afraid this not the entire error message you get.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk sorry my full error massage part one :  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 16, in <module>
    config = ConfigWrapper.new('conf/server_config.json')
  File "/home/shar/Desktop/the irwin/irwin-master/conf/ConfigWrapper.py", line 15, in new
    return ConfigWrapper(json.load(confFile))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

Comment: second part and the last :    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 20 column 5 (char 337)

Comment: It looks like your `conf/server_config.json` is ill-formatted. Can you post it on https://pastebin.com/?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I added the code to my post

Comment: Is this `//27017` supposed to be a comment?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk yes a comment

Comment: Too bad because JSON does not support comments. Remove this line and re-run `app.py`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk thanks the error gone and i have this error now Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 27, in <module>
    logging.basicConfig(format="%(message)s", level=loglevels[config.loglevel], stream=sys.stdout)
KeyError: None

Comment: I got it too. It looks like README.md is not kept in sync with the code as it says here https://github.com/clarkerubber/irwin/issues/10. Try switching to one of the previous commits that might work: `git checkout 64a73163c794fb37ee60a387159d9fc23bd2831a` and re-run `app.py`.

Comment: @shar - I suggest you update the OP with the current status of your problem.
It helps others help you by avoiding their need to follow the conversation in comments, and giving a clean picture.
I am not sure if you already did this to your current status.